# lnk4022: undecorated symbol - how to fix?

Tags: c++, linker-errors

When I link my C++ DLL program, I'm receiving the following errors and warnings:

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning LNK4022 cannot find unique match for symbol 'Init'  MTF_Garch   d:\Users\ypx7647\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch.def    1   
Warning LNK4002 "void __stdcall Init(void)" (?Init@@YGXXZ) defined in Release\MTF_Garch.obj MTF_Garch   d:\Users\ypx7647\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch.def    1   
Warning LNK4002 "public: long __thiscall ATL::CComCriticalSection::Init(void)" (?Init@CComCriticalSection@ATL@@QAEJXZ) defined in Release\stdafx.obj    MTF_Garch   d:\Users\ypx7647\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch.def    1   
Warning LNK4002 "protected: int __thiscall CAppDestinations::Init(void)" (?Init@CAppDestinations@@IAEHXZ) defined in D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\atlmfc\lib\x86\mfc140u.lib MTF_Garch   d:\Users\ypx7647\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch.def    1   
Warning LNK4002 "public: void __thiscall CMFCDragFrameImpl::Init(class CWnd *)" (?Init@CMFCDragFrameImpl@@QAEXPAVCWnd@@@Z) defined in D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\atlmfc\lib\x86\mfc140u.lib    MTF_Garch   d:\Users\ypx7647\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch.def    1   
Warning LNK4002 "protected: void __thiscall CMFCFontComboBox::Init(void)" (?Init@CMFCFontComboBox@@IAEXXZ) defined in D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\atlmfc\lib\x86\mfc140u.lib    MTF_Garch   d:\Users\ypx7647\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch.def    1   
Warning LNK4002 "protected: virtual void __thiscall CMFCPropertyGridCtrl::Init(void)" (?Init@CMFCPropertyGridCtrl@@MAEXXZ) defined in D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\atlmfc\lib\x86\mfc140u.lib    MTF_Garch   d:\Users\ypx7647\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch.def    1   
Warning LNK4002 "protected: void __thiscall CMFCPropertyGridProperty::Init(void)" (?Init@CMFCPropertyGridProperty@@IAEXXZ) defined in D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\atlmfc\lib\x86\mfc140u.lib    MTF_Garch   d:\Users\ypx7647\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch.def    1   
Warning LNK4002 "protected: void __thiscall CMFCToolBarSpinEditBoxButton::Init(void)" (?Init@CMFCToolBarSpinEditBoxButton@@IAEXXZ) defined in D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\atlmfc\lib\x86\mfc140u.lib    MTF_Garch   d:\Users\ypx7647\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch.def    1   
Warning LNK4002 "public: void __thiscall CPaneDivider::Init(int,class CWnd *)" (?Init@CPaneDivider@@QAEXHPAVCWnd@@@Z) defined in D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\atlmfc\lib\x86\mfc140u.lib MTF_Garch   d:\Users\ypx7647\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch.def    1   
Warning LNK4002 "public: void __thiscall CRecentDockSiteInfo::Init(void)" (?Init@CRecentDockSiteInfo@@QAEXXZ) defined in D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\atlmfc\lib\x86\mfc140u.lib MTF_Garch   d:\Users\ypx7647\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch.def    1   
Warning LNK4002 "public: void __thiscall CRecentPaneContainerInfo::Init(void)" (?Init@CRecentPaneContainerInfo@@QAEXXZ) defined in D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\atlmfc\lib\x86\mfc140u.lib   MTF_Garch   d:\Users\ypx7647\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch.def    1   
Warning LNK4002 "protected: void __thiscall CVSListBoxBase::Init(void)" (?Init@CVSListBoxBase@@IAEXXZ) defined in D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\atlmfc\lib\x86\mfc140u.lib    MTF_Garch   d:\Users\ypx7647\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch.def    1   
Warning LNK4002 "public: long __thiscall ATL::CComCriticalSection::Init(void)" (?Init@CComCriticalSection@ATL@@QAEJXZ) defined in D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\atlmfc\lib\x86\mfcs140u.lib   MTF_Garch   d:\Users\ypx7647\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch.def    1   
Warning LNK4002 "public: long __thiscall ATL::CComCriticalSection::Init(void)" (?Init@CComCriticalSection@ATL@@QAEJXZ) defined in D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\atlmfc\lib\x86\atls.lib   MTF_Garch   d:\Users\ypx7647\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch.def    1   
Warning LNK4002 "public: int __thiscall ATL::_stdcallthunk::Init(unsigned long,void *)" (?Init@_stdcallthunk@ATL@@QAEHKPAX@Z) defined in D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\atlmfc\lib\x86\atls.lib    MTF_Garch   d:\Users\ypx7647\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch.def    1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol Init MTF_Garch   d:\Users\ypx7647\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch\MTF_Garch.def    1   
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  MTF_Garch   d:\Users\ypx7647\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MTF_Garch\Release\MTF_Garch.lib  1
```

Clearly, there are a lot of Init's present in my VS 2017 Community solution but I'm not sure where they are coming from.

The .def file is this:

```
LIBRARY   MTF_Garch
EXPORTS  
   Init  @1 
   OnParamsChange   @2  
   Calculate   @3  
   ReplaceStr   @4
   IntrfProcsRec   @5
```

And my includes are:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "IndicatorInterfaceUnit.h"
#include "TechnicalFunctions.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Garch.h"
```

In Garch.h

```
#include <ql/auto_link.hpp>
#include <ql/quantlib.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/detail/utilities.hpp>
#include <ql/models/volatility/garch.hpp>
#include <ql/math/optimization/simplex.hpp>
#include <ql/math/optimization/levenbergmarquardt.hpp>
```

I'm not knowing using the ATL files, although it is a MFC DLL solution that I've created. The rest I'm not sure what they are.

As I am quite new to C++ could someone tell me how I go about telling the linker which Init it should use (I know there's a EXPORT syntax for the .def file but haven't been able to find the docs) or how I get rid of all the other ones that I don't need.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the mangled name of the symbol to export in the .def file.  The usual way I find these is based on the name of the undefined symbol in the error message from the linker.  I'll update the .def and rebuild.

Looking at the candidates you list, you probably want to export the symbol defined in your MTF_Garch file.  Replace the "Init @1" line in your export file to be

```
?Init@@YGXXZ @1
```

instead.  You can use mangled names for the other exports as well, but since there is only one possible symbol that the linker finds it doesn't currently need them (but may in the future).